# Dialog in a Dynamic Content Control

Tags: modal-dialog, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a custom control that contains a dynamic content control. The dynamic content displays one of several custom controls. This control is then added to the middle facet (callback1). A Navigator then controls which panel in the dynamic control displays. To this point everything works as it should. 
One of the pages that is displayed in the dynamic content has a button that calls a dialog. When the button is clicked it looks like it it is trying to display the dialog but it does not (no errors reported).
If I put the dynamic content control in a simple XPage and load this XPage and have the panel with the control that contains the button to display the dialog open by default it works fine. 
So it would appear that the Extension Library Application Layout is blocking the dialog from displaying. I'm at a loss I have the whole application working but not in the ext Library application layout. Wasting an awful lot of time, and not using the ext library app layout is not a good option either.

Comment: Changed it to a Switch control with the same results.

Comment: Bill did you check the Extlib sample database. There are dialogs inside the app layout. You might need to position the dialog outside the dynamic content control - or reconsider if you actually could get away without a dialog, but showing dynamic content

Comment: stwissel it is really strange. I created a plain jane App Layout, then added my dynamic content to it and it works so there is something in the App Layouts that I previously created that is blocking it. So I'm in the process of adding my code back into the basic App Layout and trying to find out where and why it is being blocked. Actually I don't think it is blocked it just does not display. So when I find out what is causing the problem I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. On the Application Layout custom Control I had some code in the onClientLoad with a try{}catch. If this code failed it 'blocked' the dialog box from displaying properly but the other functions of the window seems to work OK. So I'm not sure what exactly was going wrong in the inner workings of the Application Layout but I moved the code to the BeforePageLoad event and everything now works fine.
This is the code that I moved from onClientLoad to beforePageLoad :

```
if (!sessionScope.containsKey("ssHelpRepID")){
    try{
        sessionScope.put("WFSRulesRepID",database.getProfileDocument("frmConfigProfile","").getItemValue("WFSRulesRepID")[0]);
        sessionScope.put("WFSRulesRepID_formula",database.getProfileDocument("frmConfigProfile","").getItemValue("WFSRulesRepID_formula")[0]);
        sessionScope.put("WFSHelpRepID",database.getProfileDocument("frmConfigProfile","").getItemValue("WFSHelpRepID")[0]);
        sessionScope.put("WFSHelpRepID_formula",database.getProfileDocument("frmConfigProfile","").getItemValue("WFSHelpRepID_formula")[0]);
    }catch(e){
        sessionScope.put("ssError","Error in setting Rep IDs");
    }
}
```

Once I did that the original Application Layout started allowing the dialog to be displayed. Very strange, wish I could bill the time to someone :-)

Comment: I would recommend defining a session-scoped data source that is bound to the document you're referencing in these events and simply reference that data source in your other code. Remember, you can have as many data sources as you want on any given XPage...

Comment: Thanks Tim - Good thought, I sometimes get trapped in my 18 years of N/D LotusScript way of doing things. I already have 3 datasources on my main XPage and can do several things that I have wished I could do (easily) in LS, so one more linking to the profile document would be pretty simple and probably a lot easier.